# Getting an error when using concat in casperjs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, automated-tests, casperjs

Here's my code:

```
var elements = [];
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getElements() {
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll('ol.nav-primary > li > a');
   return Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('class');
   });
}

casper.start('URL', function() {
   this.waitUntilVisible('ol.nav-primary');
   casper.then(function() {
       this.echo("Nav bar is visible");
   });
});

casper.then(function() {
   elements = this.evaluate(getElements);
});

casper.then(function() {
   elements = elements.concat(this.evaluate(getElements));
});

casper.run(function() {
   this.echo(elements.length + ' elements found:');
   this.echo(' - ' + elements.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

When I run the test, this is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'elements.concat')
```

I'm just trying to write a simple script to run through and grab a list of classes to utilize in future automated tests. I basically utilized the exact code that casperjs uses as a script to scrape google and return links pulled up in a search.

I do not know why this error is coming up though.

Comment: Have you checked that you're actually on the page using `casper.capture(filename)`? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: The only sanity check I put in was the `echo` after  `this.waitUntilVisible('ol.nav-primary');`  which does echo out in terminal before I get the `TypeError`. I'll put a better one in there, but I had no reason to think I wasn't due to that.

Comment: You should try `casper.getElementsAttribute(selector, 'class')`. Maybe the page is not fully loaded. You should wait for a link and not for a nav to appear.

Comment: I tried adding `casper.getElementAttribute('head[title="Homepage"]', 'title'));`, and even tried adding `casper.test.assertHttpStatus(200);` (which returned true), but I'm still getting the `TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'elements.concat')`. It's almost as if the `.concat` itself isn't being recognized. I've fully verified that the page is indeed loading.

Comment: What PhantomJS and CasperJS versions are you using?

Comment: Casper = 1.1.0-beta3
Phantom = 1.9.0

Comment: Ok, PhantomJS 1.9.0 is probably the problem. It returns a strange result for me when I try something similar. 1.9.7 and 1.9.8 behave better, so maybe upgrade your version.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.9.8 and am still getting `TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'elements.concat')`